# Applying Mod to a long list of mixed nature

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list of the form

```
{1, 0, -3 c[3] d[2] + c[2] d[3], 2 c[3] d[2] - 3 c[2] d[3], 0, 0, -7 c[5] d[2] + 
    3 c[3] d[2]^2 - 3 c[2]^2 d[3] + 3 c[4] d[3] - 3 c[3] d[4] + 
    3 c[2] (c[3] d[2] - d[2] d[3] + d[5]),  (omitting many more such terms)  }
```

How can I reduce all coefficients modulo 3, say?

Sorry if this is a too trivial question, but nothing I do gives the desired result.

Comment: Map[If[IntegerQ[#],Mod[#,3],#]&, ReplaceAll[list, (c_*d__)/;IntegerQ[c]-> Mod[c,3]*d]] Note Mathematica then automatically changes 0*expr to 0 and if you ever have anything like c[3* expr] that will be changed to c[0].

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by Bill,

```
Map[If[IntegerQ[#],Mod[#,3],#]&, ReplaceAll[list, (c_*d__)/;
IntegerQ[c]-> Mod[c,3]*d]]
```

Note that *Mathematica* then automatically changes `0*expr` to `0`, and if you ever have anything like `c[3* expr]` that will be changed to `c[0]`.